# Aligning Mapbox text SymbolLayer with icon SymbolLayer

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm presently working on clustering symbols on a Mapbox map using a method similar to this [official example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbol-layer-clustering/). When testing, I have found that the icons and text appear as expected, *however the text layer appears to lose its alignment with the icon layer when I interact with, and rotate the map.*

I'm making use of the `PropertyFactory.iconAnchor` and `PropertyFactory.iconTranslate` [properties](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/7.0.0/index.html?com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/layers/PropertyFactory.html) when creating the `SymbolLayer` objects. Am I missing a property that is used to ensure these two layers maintain a relative position?

In case it helps, the code that I'm using to create the `SymbolLayer` objects is as follows:

```
public List<SymbolLayer> createClusterLevelSymbolLayer(int[] layers) {
    List<SymbolLayer> symbolLayers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        SymbolLayer symbolLayer = new SymbolLayer("cluster-" + i, "points");
        symbolLayer.setProperties(
                iconImage("circle-15"),
                iconTranslate(new Float[]{1f, 13f}),
                iconSize(1.5f),
                iconAnchor(Property.ICON_ANCHOR_BOTTOM)
        );

        Expression pointCount = toNumber(get("point_count"));
        symbolLayer.setFilter(
                i == 0
                        ? all(has("point_count"),
                        gte(pointCount, literal(layers[i]))
                ) : all(has("point_count"),
                        gt(pointCount, literal(layers[i])),
                        lt(pointCount, literal(layers[i - 1]))
                )
        );
        symbolLayers.add(symbolLayer);
    }

    return symbolLayers;
}

public SymbolLayer createClusterTextLayer() {
    return new SymbolLayer("count", "points").withProperties(
            textField(Expression.toString(get("point_count"))),
            textSize(12f),
            textColor(Color.BLACK),
            textIgnorePlacement(true),
            textAllowOverlap(true),
            textAnchor(Property.TEXT_ANCHOR_BOTTOM)
    );
}
```

---

**Edit (07/02/2019 @ 10:15am)**
As per @riastrad's recommendation, please find screenshots of the behaviour that I'm experiencing, below:

[image: Upon booting into the app, the clustered symbol appears just fine, with icon beneath a text layer (aligned well).] **(Above)** Upon booting into the app, the clustered symbol appears just fine, with icon beneath a text layer (aligned well).

**(Below)** However when gesturing to rotate the map, both icon and text separate until the view/camera position are returned to their starting point

[image: Misaligned text SymbolLayer over icon SymbolLayer (approximate 90 degree rotation)]

[image: Misaligned text SymbolLayer over icon SymbolLayer (approximate 180 degree rotation)]

Comment: Are you able to update your question with an image or screen capture that demonstrates the loss of alignment between the text and the icon layer? This example has a similar implementation: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbol-layer-clustering/ and I'm not seeing any misalignment when I run it on a Pixel 3  (the example is also available on the [Mapbox Demo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo&hl=en_US))

Comment: Not a problem @riastrad, I've since added screenshots illustrating the behaviour as per your request. Funnily enough, I've compared my implementation to [the implementation that you linked](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbol-layer-clustering/) and I can't seem to see anything amiss (I hope it's not something obvious that I'm missing!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is happening because you are setting a value for [`icon-translate`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-symbol-icon-translate) for your icon `SymbolLayer`.

Per the linked documentation, this represents the:

> Distance that the icon's anchor is moved from its original placement.

So essentially you are anchoring both your text & icon to the bottom, but at the same time you are shifting your icon over by `Float[]{1f, 13f}`.

The solution should be to either set the same values for your [`text-translate`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-symbol-text-translate) or remove it from your icon `SymbolLayer` altogether.

Comment: For context, the `iconTranlate` property is used in the example you linked to in order to visually "center" the text value within the triangle image.

Comment: I think you're spot on @riastrad, however the issue that I'm experiencing now that I've removed the `iconTranslate` property is that the text `SymbolLayer` is aligned to the bottom of the icon (they do seem to move in unison though!). Is there a correct method for visually centering the text `SymbolLayer` on the icon `SymbolLayer` without creating creating the alignment issue again?

Comment: Nice - glad we've nearly got it. Is there a specific reason you feel like you need to be using an anchor? The default behavior is to center both elements based on the `lat/lon` in your data

Comment: trust me to over-complicate things! Removing both the `iconAnchor` and `textAnchor` from my layer creator methods worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your ongoing assistance with this - you hit the nail on the head with your responses, thanks again.